# Firebase database rules not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using **Firebase real-time database** for my web app. I have a node in the database named **Users** which looks like this:

```
Users{
    userID{
        Name
        Post
        Type
        AutoRefresh
        Uploads{
            upload1
            upload2
        }
        News{
            news1
            news2
        }
        Friends{
            friend1
            friend2
        }
        Requests{
            req1
            req2
        }
    }
}
```

I have set the following database rules for this node:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      "$userID": {
        ".write": "auth.uid === $userID && !newData.hasChild('Post') && !newData.hasChild('Type') && !newData.hasChild('Friends') && !newData.hasChild('Requests') && !newData.hasChild('Uploads') && !newData.hasChild('News')"
      }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I am trying to write some value in the location **Users/userID/AutoRefresh** from my web app, I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied
    at Repo.js:510
    at Object.t.exceptionGuard (util.js:536)
    at e.callOnCompleteCallback (Repo.js:501)
    at Repo.js:278
    at PersistentConnection.js:402
    at t.wt (PersistentConnection.js:435)
    at e.wt (Connection.js:262)
    at e.ln (Connection.js:256)
    at t.onMessage (Connection.js:157)
    at t.Wn (WebSocketConnection.js:197)
```

I am using the following code to perform write operation:

```
firebase.database().ref().child('Users/' + userID + '/AutoRefresh').set('Off').then(function(){
 //Do something
});
```

When I test this write operation in the simulator of Firebase console, it perfectly writes the new value in the **AutoRefresh** node. Why it's not working in the app? Am I doing something wrong?

This problem occurred after applying the rules. Before applying rules, it was working perfectly.

Comment: It looks like your rule requires any set data to have children like `Post`, but you don't have this in your set call.

Comment: Rules I gave includes !newData.hasChild('Post') which means that there can't be any data with the key "Post". @MattWay

Comment: Missed that sorry. Have you tried removing your rule, and progressively adding each part of the rule back, and testing?

Comment: It looks like one of these clauses is not true: `!newData.hasChild('Post') && !newData.hasChild('Type') && !newData.hasChild('Friends') && !newData.hasChild('Requests') && !newData.hasChild('Uploads') && !newData.hasChild('News')`. Which one is impossible for us to say, so I'd indeed do what Matt says and disable them one by one. Note that `newData` is not just contain the data that you update with `set()`; it contains the full data at `/Users/$userID` as it will exist if the set succeeds. So if the location already contains a `Type` property, the write will fail.

Comment: I tested as you guys said, and yes, it is because of !newData.hasChild('Post'). The error occurs if the UserID node contains "Post" or other nodes I specified in rules.