# Disable write in specific child using Firebase database rules

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50320747/firebase-database-rules-not-working) previously about Firebase database rules. That question was not specific enough, because I didn't know the actual reason for the error. As I didn't get any working solution for my problem, I am posting this question with a more specific description.

I am using Firebase real-time database for my web application. I am maintaining the following structure in the database:

```
{
    Users:{
        userID:{
            Name
            Post
        }
    }
}
```

I want authenticated users to have read and write access to **Name**. But I don't want them to have write access to **Post**.

So, I have tried this with the following database rule:

```
"rules": {
    "Users": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      "$userID": {
        ".write": "auth.uid == $userID && !newData.hasChild('Post')"
      }
    }
 }
```

The problem is, this rule is denying write permission for both **Name** and **Post** node. I am getting **permission denied** error when I am trying to write **Name** with the following code:

```
firebase.database().ref().child('Users/' + user.uid + '/Name').set(name).then(function(){
       // Do something
});
```

Am I doing something wrong in writing rules? How should I write database rules to disable write access to **Post** node only?

**UPDATE:** For now, I have solved it by writing rules for each child seperately in the following way:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      "$userID": {
         "Name": {
            ".write": "$userID == auth.uid"
         },
         "Post": {
            ".write": false
         }
       }
     }
   }
}
```

But this results in a very lengthy rule when I have lots of child nodes. It would be helpful if someone suggests an easier way to write the rule to disable write access to specific child nodes.

Comment: Please don't repost your question. Instead you should update [your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50320747/firebase-database-rules-not-working)!

Comment: The previous one was not specific enough, because I didn't know the specific cause of the problem... That's why I posted with a more specific description. In the previous question, I asked the cause of the error. As I found the cause now, in this question I am asking for a solution. In this sense, I don't think this is a duplicate. If I am wrong, please suggest me what to do now. @AndréKool

Comment: And the previous question doesn't have the answer to this question. I have edited the post by the way. @AndréKool